# is it possible to set fully transparent background to the layout of the service class

Tags: android, service, foreground-service, system-alert-window

[image: demo 1]I am running a service of type `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` and i have inflated a layout to the service

```
private void createLayoutForServiceClass() {
    inflater=(LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    windowManager=(WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);


    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            //WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_INPUT_METHOD |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,// | WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.TOP;
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.area_selection, null);

    windowManager.addView(view, params);
}
```

Now when i set the background of the layout it returns me the black background, i want the background to be fully transparent so that user can see that is running on the screen along with he/she can perform her task while he/she is not disturbed in doing the work.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#B94765">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_cross"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_close_black_24dp"/>

</LinearLayout>

<com.steelkiwi.cropiwa.CropIwaView
    android:id="@+id/crop_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" /></LinearLayout>
```

Is it possible to set the background of the layout to fully transparent.
I have made activity transparent,fragment transparent, dialog transparent but this is new to me can anyone suggest me good idea

Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this in your layout xml:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Also, have a look at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-do-i-create-a-transparent-activity-on-android/2700683#2700683)

Comment: #Nikos_hidalgo :- i m not asking for the activity i m asking for the service class

Comment: have you tried adding my code to the service class' layout file before inflating it? Also, could you please post your layout for the service class?

Comment: if you add any other colour instead of transparent/black, does it actually display that colour or is it still black?

Comment: if i add this as background color android:background="#B94765" then the result is this please check the attached pic with the question

Comment: the color only applied to the the imageview linear layout but not to its child layout

Comment: if that's the full code on your layout, I think you have a tag </LinearLayout> missing at the end. Also, have you tried adding the attribute to both layouts?

Comment: no its not the full code i linear layout tag is missing while attaching the code of my layout

Comment: so have you tried adding the transparent attribute everytime you open a tag with a new layout?

Comment: now i have edited my layout code once again you can have a look

Comment: yes i have tried in each and every new layout but nothing work for me